# Porque los elementos salen de esta manera?

Tags: php, html, css

alguien podría ayudarme con esto? Porque se ve así?
[image: stackoverflow]

```
  <option name="grupo_pertenece" id="grupo_pertenece" value="Grupo 2">Grupo 2   <?php
                          $sql = "select * from as_users"; 
                          $ds = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                          while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ds)){
                              echo "{$fila['grupo_pertenece']}";
       }
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer  `<option>$algo</option>` para cada resultado de la consulta, dentro del while. Cada option es una opción seleccionable en el select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<select>
  <option>Hola mundo</option>
  <!--IMPRIMES POR PHP-->
  
  
</select>
```

Algo que estás haciendo tu, es que confundiste option con select, select es el input que contiene los option, vas a hacer un while cada vez que haga un echo, ejemplo:

TU CODIGO:

```
<option name="grupo_pertenece" id="grupo_pertenece" value="Grupo 2">Grupo 2   <?php
                      $sql = "select * from as_users"; 
                      $ds = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                      while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ds)){
                          echo "{$fila['grupo_pertenece']}";
   }
```

EL CODIGO ARREGLADO:

```
<select id="grupo_que_pertenece">
  <option>Seleccione una opción</option>
  <?php
    $sql = "select * from as_users"; 
    $ds = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ds)){
      echo '<option value="'.$fila['grupo_pertenece'].'">'.$fila['grupo_pertenece'].'</option>';
   }
  ?>
</select>
```